# Read from Python to Spark in a distributed way

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, opentsdb

I'm using OpenTSDB database which stores the collected metrics and values on HBase. However, it is stored as BLOB format (Binary large object), which makes it difficult to leverage engines like Pig or Hive for data processing since data os not stored in a common way.

I decided to switch to Spark engine to process collected data.

I found this python client for my database https://github.com/wiktorski/opentsdb_pandas which is actually able to read all my database into a pandas.core.series.Series structure.

I want to use that python code and submit it into Spark using spark-submit and process the data i read in a distributed way (which implies transforming pandas series to RDD before processing).

So my questions are :

- Since i passed the python reader code through spark-submit, is the reading over my database parallelized ?
- If no, how can I make the data available for all executors so I don't have to load the whole dataset in memory ?
- Do i need to use Spark context methods to perform a parallelized read ?